# How make HTTP requests in Electron JS, upon the window opening/closing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm working with Electron JS (for the first time), alongside React JS.

I'm trying to make HTTP requests when the window is opened/closed, but can't figure out how. From basic console logs, I've found these 2 functions below are fired when I close down the app from the browser. Before the app closes, I'm trying to make a HTTP request to update a users login status.

```
const logout = async (_data) => {
return await axios.PUT('URL_HERE', _data)
}
```

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {

    logout(someData)
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

```
 mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    logout(someData)

    mainWindow = null
  })
```

My index.js (there isn't an index.html file) file is looking like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App  from "./components/App"

let root = document.createElement('div')

root.id = 'root'
document.body.appendChild(root)

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

How can I go about this? Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Using async should solve the issue `app.on('window-all-closed', async () => { if(process.platform !== 'darwin') { await logout(someData); app.quit(); }})`

However I don't think it's a good idea to logout from the client.
It would probably be better to use sockets or polling and logout the user from the server when the connection is terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an HTTP request when the window is opened or closed in Electron, you can use the `ipcRenderer.send()` method. This method allows you to send a message to the main process from the renderer process.

To use `ipcRenderer.send()`, you first need to create an IPC channel. This can be done by calling the `ipcRenderer.createChannel()` method. The first argument to this method is the name of the channel.

Once you have created an IPC channel, you can send a message to the main process by calling the `ipcRenderer.send()` method. The first argument to this method is the name of the channel, and the second argument is the message.

The main process will receive the message and can then take any action that it needs to. In your case, you can use the message to make an HTTP request to update a user's login status.

Here is an example of how to use `ipcRenderer.send()` to make an HTTP request when the window is opened or closed:

```
// Create an IPC channel
const channel = ipcRenderer.createChannel('my-channel');
​
// Send a message to the main process when the window is opened
ipcRenderer.on('window-open', () => {
  channel.send('open');
});
​
// Send a message to the main process when the window is closed
ipcRenderer.on('window-close', () => {
  channel.send('close');
});
​
// In the main process, listen for messages from the renderer process
ipcMain.on('my-channel', (event, message) => {
  // Make an HTTP request to update the user's login status
  fetch('https://example.com/api/update-login-status', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: 'user@example.com',
      loggedIn: true,
    }),
  });
});
```

I hope this helps!